# Как сделать, чтобы при вводе пароля, если человек нажимал Esc, программа бы закрывалась

Tags: c++, windows

Подскажите, можно ли сделать, чтобы, например, при вводе пароля, если человек нажимал <kbd>Esc</kbd>, программа закрывалась бы.

Именно не до начала ввода, и не после, а в любой момент. К примеру, я ввел `1223` и потом нажал <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: Конечно можно, если вы читаете по одному символу и анализируете каждый из них (чтение символов по одному (без ожидания нажатия Enter) системозависимо, поэтому добавьте к вопросу указание вашей ОС))

Comment: Да, конечно, сделал)

Comment: Прога консольная или оконная? Как именно у вас происходит ввод пароля?

Comment: Один вариант есть. Второй вариант SetWindowHookEx + WH_KEYBOARD, активный элемент проверить можно через GetFocus

Comment: консольная. блин неужели так тяжело.

Comment: @kirill, я не пишу в винде, но гугл советует что-то вроде этого с [kbhit](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/sprd/kbhit.php)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос операционную систему и что программа консольная. Без этого не помогут.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт об использовании WinAPI, то для подобных целей в Windows существует так называемый субклассинг окон. Это когда заменяется оконная процедура (в нашем случае эдитконтрола), которая перехватывает и по-своему обрабатывает сообщения (в нашем случае - WM_KEYDOWN). Для иллюстрации я тут "на коленке" набросал пример, который работает под Win64 (под Win32 принцип тот же, хоть код будет немного другой).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>


WNDPROC g_editWndProc;


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG msg;

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "EDIT", NULL, WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_LEFT | 
                           ES_PASSWORD | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
                            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 100, 10,
                            NULL, NULL, hInstance, 0);
    if(!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"Can't create the main window!","Fatal error",MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1;
    }


    g_editWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)WndProc);

    ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if (wParam==VK_ESCAPE) DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        return CallWindowProc(g_editWndProc, hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);


    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            char szBuf[100];
            char szBuf2[1000];
            GetWindowText(hWnd, szBuf, 99);
            snprintf(szBuf2, 1000, "You enterd password: %s", szBuf);
            MessageBox(hWnd, szBuf2, "Password", MB_OK);
        }
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)g_editWndProc);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }

    return CallWindowProc(g_editWndProc, hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
}
```